# If any two curves in a topological space $X$ with same initial and end points are homotopic then $X$ is simply connected

Tags: general-topology

This supposes to be trivial, but I am not seeing it. What I should prove is that there exists some point $p\in X$ such that the fundamental group of $X$ with point $p$ is a trivial group. let $\gamma , \eta$ be curves with the initial and end point being the same, then they are homotopic. Then I would think if I pick the base point $p$ be the initial/end point of these closed curves, then the fundamental group $\pi(X,p)$ would be trivial. But shouldn't the $\pi(X,p)=\{\gamma | \gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ is a closed curve $\}$, which is not the trivial group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental group consists of equivalence classes of curves (beginning and ending at the same point) under homotopy. So if all such curves are homotopic, then there is only one equivalence class, which makes the fundamental group trivial.